# Why is delegation to Account not working when it is specified as a NotPrincipal in a Bucket policy with Deny effect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

As per AWS documentation,

> When you use an AWS account identifier as the principal in a policy,
> you delegate authority to the account.

This delegation works fine when an AWS account identifier is specified in the Principal element of an Allow statement of a Bucket policy. In this case, it is not required to specify the individual IAM users in the Principal element (Of course, there must be an IAM policy that grants the IAM users access to bucket).

However, this delegation does not appear to work when an AWS account identifier is specified in the NotPrincipal element of a Deny statement - Refer policy below. In this case, you still need to specify the individual IAM users within the Account to be excluded from the Deny - why is this so?

Let us say I have an Administrator user in an account but the following Bucket Policy denies S3 access even to this Administrator user.

Why is that the Administrator also needs to be specified in the NotPrincipal element in policy below? Specifying the ARN for account / root in NotPrincipal should have automatically excluded the Administrator or any IAM user in that account - right? Why is delegation to Account not working here in the case of NotPrincipal?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1544958708832",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1544958705029",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>","arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update:**
In a Bucket Policy, I find it difficult to understand the conflicting behavior with **Effect:Allow, Principal: Account ARN**  and **Effect:Deny, NotPrincipal:Account ARN**. With **Effect:Allow, Principal: Account ARN**, the Account has delegation privileges i.e. Account can control using an IAM policy which IAM users can further be granted access.
However, **Effect:Deny, NotPrincipal:Account ARN** does not seem to delegate (the exclusion of Deny) to the Account. Even if the IAM user inside Account has permissions via an IAM policy, **it still needs to be specifically added in the NotPrincipal element**.

To summarize, **Effect:Allow, Principal: Account ARN** says

> Allow this Account and all its IAM users that are granted access by Account

Applying same logic, **Effect:Deny, NotPrincipal:Account ARN** should ideally say

> Deny everyone except this Account and all its IAM users that are granted access by Account

But this is not the case, **Effect:Deny, NotPrincipal:Account ARN** does not seem to delegate the exclusion to the IAM users in the Account. They need to be specified explicitly in NotPrincipal element to be excluded.

**Effect:Deny, NotPrincipal:Account ARN** seems to include only the Account root but not its IAM users (even if IAM users have access eg:- Administrator in this case). On the contrary, **Effect:Allow, Principal: Account ARN** includes both the Account root and its IAM users (that has access via IAM policy).

Comment: What action is this Administrator user trying to perform? Also, it'd be helpful if you post the error message.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want your admin user to access this bucket, or deny this to the admin user?

Comment: Thanks, my question was around the fact that by including the ARN of the account, the whole account and IAM users under that account should have been excluded from the deny but that is not the case - If an Administrator user needs to be excluded, it still need to be specified explicitly. I am comparing this to the behavior in the case of a statement with Effect:Allow & the Principal as Account ARN where an Administrator IAM user has access without needing to specify it explicitly in the Principal.

Comment: i.e. when using Effect:Allow and Principal: Account ARN, (in the Principal element) there is no need to explicitly specify the IAM users under the Account that needs to be granted access - the Account is left to decide via IAM policy to grant access or not. However, in the case of Effect:Deny and NotPrincipal: Account ARN, you need to specify the IAM users to exclude explicitly (the Account ARN alone is not sufficient) - Why is the whole account not trusted in this case? similar to the Effect:Allow and Principal:Account ARN scenario.

Comment: To summarize, a statement with Effect:Allow and Principal: Account ARN extends the Allow to include all IAM users inside that Account (Of course access still needs to be granted via IAM or Bucket policy). However, a statement with Effect:Deny and NotPrincipal: Account ARN does not exclude the IAM users inside that account - they still need to be specified explicitly inside the NotPrincipal to be excluded from Deny - Why so? I am more curious about the difference in the way inclusion and exclusion works when Account ARN is specified in the Principal and NotPrincipal elements.

Comment: Effect:Allow and Principal: Account ARN applies to the Account as well as IAM users inside the Account whereas Effect:Deny and NotPrincipal: Account ARN applies to (excludes) only the Account root but does not exclude the IAM users of that Account.

Comment: I think it boils to the fact that AWS treats `Allow` and `Deny` differently. `Deny` always wins and it overwrites any allows. Thus if you use `Effect:Deny` with  `NotPrincipal:Account`, you deny everyone, except the root of the account. AWS is very strict about `Deny` and it will  prioritize `Deny` over everything else. If the delegation worked here as you are describing, then `Deny` would lead to potential implicit `Allow` to IAM users (through IAM policies) which would be security concern.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin.To your comment "Deny would lead to potential implicit Allow to IAM users (through IAM policies)"- in fact even an explicit Allow to IAM users will not work in this case. Basically, the delegation to Account root mechanism is a special scenario that works only with an Allow. You cannot delegate to an Account just by excluding it in NotPrincipal.It is the Allow that facilitates delegation. A Deny can never delegate at an Account level by excluding the Account root in NotPrincipal i.e. Only Allows delegates to Account Root either via inclusion or exclusion - your thoughts @Marcin?

Comment: My original question shortened - "An explicit allow to IAM users works when the Account (Root) ARN is included in the Principal element of an Allow statement.
On the contrary, an explicit allow to IAM users does not work when the Account (Root) ARN is included in the NotPrincipal element of a Deny statement" - All our discussions point to the fact that "Delegation of Authority to Account" is not decided by Principal or NotPrincipal elements and instead, it is the Allow that facilitates delegation (& Deny can never delegate).

Delegation seem to work only with Allows but not Denies.