# AWS Account delegation does not work when account identifier is specified as NotPrincipal in a Deny statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

I asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65042607/7865060). I thought to add more clarity in this question.

As per AWS documentation,

> **NotPrincipal With Deny**
> When you use NotPrincipal in the same policy
> statement as "Effect": "Deny", the actions specified in the policy
> statement are explicitly denied to all principals except for the ones
> specified.

and

> When you use an AWS account identifier as the principal in a policy,
> you delegate authority to the account.

Delegation to an Account works when the Account (Root) ARN is included in the Principal element of an Allow statement.
On the contrary, Delegation to an Account does not work when the Account (Root) ARN is included in the NotPrincipal element of a Deny statement.

Which leads me to think - A Deny can never delegate to an Account even by excluding the Account root in NotPrincipal i.e. you still need to specify explicitly the individual IAM users in the NotPrincipal element of policy to be excluded from Deny. This behavior is very different to an Allow where only the Account (Root) needs to be specified for further delegation - no need to specify explicitly which IAM users should be included as part of Allow.

**Question: Does delegation of authority to the account apply only in an Allow statement** ? i.e. Is it correct to assume that the delegation of authority to the account does not apply in a Deny statement even if the account is excluded via NotPrincipal element?

**Scenario 1: Allow delegates with just the Account (Root) ARN**

Bucket Policy below will let Account decide via its IAM policies which IAM users in the Account can access the bucket - delegation works.

```
 "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
                },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::abhiawsbucket-accessdemo",
            "arn:aws:s3:::abhiawsbucket-accessdemo/*"
        ]
```

**Scenario 2: Deny does not delegate with just the Account (Root) ARN**

Bucket Policy below will **NOT** let Account decide via its IAM policies which IAM users in the Account can access the bucket - delegation does NOT work. Specifying the Account (Root) ARN in NotPrincipal element does not delegate.

```
 "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
                },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::abhiawsbucket-accessdemo",
            "arn:aws:s3:::abhiawsbucket-accessdemo/*"
        ]
```

To summarize, I am trying to find out if the following statement is correct

> Delegation to Account (Root) can be implemented via Principal
> and NotPrincipal elements but Delegation itself works / applies only
> with **Effect:Allow**. Delegation to Account (Root) does NOT work with **Effect:Deny** even when Account (Root) is excluded in NotPrincipal.

Comment: Please edit your question to include examples of the policy that is causing you a problem, so that we can attempt to reproduce the situation.

Comment: @John Rotenstein - added more examples and clarity to question